# ASP.NET MVC - View Model pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, standards, view-model-pattern

I have only been working with the MVC framework (ASP.NET MVC2/3/Razor) for a few months now and I am really enjoying it, however I am having a hard time figuring out a standard for View Models.  In my projects, I have a Models folder (Contains my data models - Linq DBML, Repository[ies], Extension methods) and a Models/ViewModels folder.  My view models are usually reusable classes which usually just contain simple get/set properties for the LINQ objects or collections of objects I need to access for a particular view.

Now the problem I am having is figuring out when to create a view model.  My goal is to use the LINQ object as the view model as often as possible, especially when it is an Edit action.  My problem is what if I have other bits of data that I might want to use for display purposes only?  I don't like to use the ViewData/ViewBag collections, as accessing members of these requires knowledge of the collection item's key (not easy for a designer/front-end guy to "guess").  I also don't like the idea of creating a ViewModel for each View, as it seems like unnecessarily messy code.

For example, imagine I have a data model for an Employee, and I want to display some information unrelated to that employee - say, site statistics, dynamic menus, and whatever else you can think of that might come from the database.  What model should I pass the /Employee/Edit action?  The Employee object with a bunch of ViewData[] for the rest, or a custom EmployeeView?

Is there a gold standard?  What am I missing?  What are you doing different that I should look into?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've named three things here:

- Site statistics
- Dynamic menus
- Whatever else [...] *might come from the database*

That third point is a trap; just because something is in your database, *doesn't mean it's part of your domain model.*

Navigation *might* be based on a database.  It might also be be in a site map or hard-coded into the application.  It's actually not application *data*, it's application *configuration*. If you're storing it in the application database, that's OK (well, not really), but it is **not** part of the model itself.

Similarly, site statistics usually are stored in a database, but they're stored in a *different* database, specifically an analytics database (and many people just "outsource" this to Google).  So again, they are a *kind* of data, but they are not your model.

If you want your application to make sense, you need to separate these concerns at a conceptual level.  Navigation gets done in your master page/layout, including whatever dynamic code is necessary to make it work.  It is *pure* view logic - don't let it leak into your model.  It's completely OK and usually preferable to use the ViewData/ViewBag for concerns that are ancillary to the actual feature that is currently in use.

Now, assuming there are other kinds of view data that actually *are* application data: It's true *in principle* that views are supposed to be connected directly to models - that is after all what "MVC" means - but in practice, it's just a re-implementation of the ill-conceived "canonical data model" idea.  Domain and presentation are separate concerns, and as such, imply different contextual models - in the latter case, that's a View Model.

When I first started doing MVC work, I was reluctant to use view models as well.  But after I became more accustomed to the idea, I realized that it was really the *only* tenable solution - especially when your "model" is mostly a thin wrapper over the database itself.  Views and data change in different ways and at different rates; if you don't want to be worrying about a constant stream of bugs and regressions then you *need* some insulation between the two.  Build a mapping layer and call it a day.

At this point I've taken to creating a different view model for *every* view, whether I think I need it or not.  At the beginning, it might be nothing but a carbon copy of a model class, but it means I can tweak it at any time and in any manner without having to screw around with the underlying model - and vice versa.  [As tv says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077913/asp-net-mvc-view-model-pattern/6077961#6077961), the initial view model is trivially easy to generate with [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/), and will take up maybe 30 seconds of your time.

Just use view models, and hope that eventually the tools support view-model auto-generation.

Comment: While I understand the separation of concerns, I love the simplicity of calling UpdateModel().  Why add yet another layer with AutoMapper (which I have to be honest, I haven't looked at yet) if its seemingly unnecessary?  I agree that if View Models were intended to be such an important part of the MVC framework, why weren't they included as a part of the tools/wizards?  Something seems off here, to me at least.

Comment: @Keith: First, AutoMapper isn't a "layer", it's a convention-based mapper which virtually eliminates all the mapping code you'd otherwise have to write. Second, it only seems unnecessary at the very beginning; inevitably it becomes necessary soon after. Last but not least, the term "View" tends to get taken too literally, just as "Model" does - View Models are part of the View just as Repositories are part of the Model. This is in fact how most good architectures are designed; each layer or component has its own contextual model and when you want to jump from one to the next, you map.

Comment: @Keith: As for "I love the simplicity of calling UpdateModel()" - [You still do that, you just use the parameterized method overload](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/17/asp-net-mvc-using-controller-updatemodel-when-using-a-viewmodel/).

Comment: if my viewmodel has two different models (suppose, model1 and model2) in it, then how do i load the viewmodel using which repository? model1's repository or model2's repository?

Answer (score 3):

I never use my entity classes directly as view models.  I always create a view-specific model for each view containing the data for that view.  I've started using AutoMapper to map between view models and entity models. I mediate this through a ModelMapper class that has a `ToViewModel<TEntity,TViewModel>()` method for handing standard mappings (just invokes the automapper) and specialized mapping methods for custom mappings, especially to support creating and updating entities from view models.

Comment: What do your View Models look like?  I've seen everything from near-copies of the LINQ objects they represent to complex classes with tons of business logic methods (which seems like a NO-NO for a View Model).  Mine are, as described above, simple classes with get/set properties for my LINQ data objects.

Comment: @Keith - typically simple containers, but I do model-level validation so the properties are decorated with appropriate attributes (as are the entity models).  Business logic (other than attribute-based validation) is isolated in the model mapping class and in the repository infrastructure.  In addition I have a specification provider for query specifications that implements business-level access policies, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If You create page for editing employee but You also display things You mentioned (site statistics/menus) why not put them in partial views or layout files?

Comment: With Partial Views, you still need to pass a model to display data dynamically.